# Games with rubbing/scratching as interaction?

Tags: game-design, game-mechanics

I'm brainstorming a game aimed for touchscreen. Its primary interaction involves a lot of rubbing and scratching with the finger to the on screen objects, sort of like Fruit Ninja, but a bit more work than a single swipe. I recall there are somewhat similar operation in Rayman Raving Rabbid that uses Wiimote to draw shapes.

At this stage, the interactions in my mind looks repetitive and unappealing. I'm trying to find similar examples that appear repetitive but still fun to play. Besides these two, are there any others?

Comment: You might get a better response on Gaming.StackExchange.com.

Comment: Gaming.SE doesn't want these types of questions.

Comment: @ashes999, I can't find a relevant tag on gaming.se. Maybe it's more suitable here?

Comment: This is a "list of things" type question, which generally isn't applicable to any SE site.

Comment: "repetitive and unappealing" I think you nailed it right there. See also: http://penny-arcade.com/patv/episode/kinect-disconnect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go out in the real world and observe things with rubbing or scratching.  Proceed to translate into game ideas.

Things that come to mind...

- Pet a cat
- Scratch a dog's ear
- Itch (Itching with Friends?)
- Lottery tickets
- Polishing silver
- Washing dishes
- Wash floors / wipe down counters
- Sex (self, with others)
- Spot of food on shirt just before meeting
- Runny nose
- Bathroom
- How does my monitor get so messy?  What's with these fingerprints!  Ugh - it's not a touch screen!
- Brush teeth
- Wash hair (lather, rinse, repeat)
- Chipping old paint
- Washing cars
- Butler ("Sir, a speck of lint on your shoulder *flick flick*")

Comment: No problem.  Some would consider it a silly question, and some of my answers were somewhat silly, but it's these very interactions of life that would translate so well to a touch interface.

Comment: I love how you wait until the middle of the list to put ___SEX___, when the closest I thought you'd get was _itching with friends_

Answer (score 1):

A lot of DS games use this mechanic, Cooking or Crafting Mama would be good examples, and lots of other girl's games. I think key ways to make this mechanic fun are to have particles/good feedback while rubbing and a rewarding reveal once the rub has finished.

Tim's suggestion is spot on, the "fun" from doing these things is how it mimics real life.